# Android's TextView not showing specific digits

Tags: android, textview, numbers

I can't display specific numbers in a `TextView`. This happens when I am trying both to update the view's `text` programmaticaly or in just in the xml.

Here is the TextView as defined in a layout file,

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

I can also see that in the Android Studio editor. If I set `text` to 1, 2 and 3 I can see the number displayed. But if I set `text` to 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 then there's nothing.

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**
I am adding two screenshots directly from the Android Studio's layout editor.
Each screenshot represents the same textview with different values:

For `text="123"`,

[image]

and now for `text="142"`,

[image]

Note: The `4` seems to take a character's space in the `TextView` but it's not being displayed.

Comment: Debug textview value, by logging `textview.getText()`. Check logs what is textview current value.

Comment: I've done it! The text is what's expected to be @Heisenberg.

Comment: check this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144142/custom-font-not-showing-properly-some-characters

Comment: Damn it man @MohammedAlaa, keen observation! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the specific font-family was not able to display all of the digits.